# how to access webpage hosted on tomcat server from the android mobile

Tags: android, jsp, tomcat

I have designed a webpage and run that on my browser using tomcat server `http://localhost:8084/neclogin/main.jsp`

I also accessed it from my android emulator it works well.
`http://10.0.2.2:8084/neclogin/main.jsp` it works well.

But when I tried on my real device (connected to PC via hotspot) 
`http://192.xxx.xxx.xxx:8084/neclogin/web/main.jsp`

It shows on browser that HTTTP 404 ERROR - DESCRIPTION :requested resource is unavailable

I am confused whether my android mobile is unable to connect to localhost or can't trace the path of my main.jsp

FOR MORE DETAIL

```
1)windows 7
2)NETBEANS IDE WITH APACHE TOMCAT SERVER 8.03
3)**Both connected via wifi hotspot on my mobile**
4)path to my main.jsp is `C:\Users\dell\Documents\NetBeansProjects\neclogin\web\main.jsp`
5)path to my tomcat server installed is `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 8.0.3`
```

**i have disabled my windows and antivirus firewall**

Comment: why you have this "/web" ? on the last URL?

Comment: that is the path to access main.jsp

Comment: and howcome in the first 2 urls there is no /web?
its very logical that url 1&2 have different results, because they are not the same, which one is correct? use it :)

Answer (score 3):

First try to access `http://192.xxx.xxx.xxx:8084/neclogin/web/main.jsp` from your PC to see if the IP is correct.

a) If that works and you can access it, then indeed there is a problem with the external access and the problem is somewhere in your firewall settings or alike. Potentially it doesn't let traffic through 'non-standard' ports (80,433 etc)

b) If you can't access it on your PC either using then you got the IP wrong. Try running `ipconfig` from the command line and see if with the IP listed there it works. `ipconfig` will return a bunch of different IPs you need to look for the one that starts with 192 most likely labeled as IPv4 or [something like that](http://www.bobborst.com/tools/whatsmyip/win7-ip-results.png).

It's also worth checking what the 404 message looks like. If it's [tomcat's 404 page](http://img251.imageshack.us/img251/5042/tomcat404.png) then you're almost there as you can access tomcat but not using the correct path.